# Batch program unexpected when I type something

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, batch-processing

Ok, so I've made a batch game and I'm writing through the tutorial right now. My plan is to make %roll%

```
set /a roll=(%random% %% 7) + 1
```

Capable of taking away `%enhealth%` and `%yourhealth%`

```
:foresttutorial
cls
echo.
echo   __________________________
echo  |                          |
echo  | An enemy appeared!       |
echo  | Enemy health: %enhealth% |
echo  | Your health: %yourhealth%|
echo  |                          |
echo  | 1. ATK    2. USE POT     |
echo  | 3. GOLD   4. PASS        |
echo  | _________________________|
echo.
echo Here appears an attack screen!
echo Quick, press 1 and enter!
set /p choice8
if %choice8% == 1 goto atkforesttutorial1 else goto invalidforesttutorial1

:invalidforesttutorial1
cls
echo Invalid answer. You can try the other options soon,
echo for now just press 1.
pause
goto foresttutorial

:atkforesttutorial1
set /a roll=(%random% %% 7) + 1
set enhealth = %enhealth% - %roll%
echo You attacked the enemy!
echo.
echo   __________________________
echo  |                          |
echo  | An enemy appeared!       |
echo  | Enemy health: %enhealth% |
echo  | Your health: %yourhealth%|
echo  |                          |
echo  | 1. ATK    2. USE POT     |
echo  | 3. GOLD   4. PASS        |
echo  | _________________________|
echo.
pause
```

Above is my code. When I type in 1 for the FIRST box, and click enter, it pops up with a flash that says "1 was unexpected..." or something similar. Any ideas on how to fix this?
Full code here:
https://pastebin.com/kBNgNV1G

Comment: `|` is a special character in batch. Don't use it. (or use `^|` if you absolutely must use it)

Comment: Funny, no problems when I run the code, only when I type 1 :/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Althought it didn't fix the code, it helped me debug the code :)

EDIT: Nevermind, I came across another bug and using the ^| helped me. Thanks.

Comment: It should be `Set/P "choice8= "` you need the **`=`** as it appears elsewhere in your code; and you **do** need to escape those pipes, **`|`**, with a caret, **`^`**. Also `set enhealth = %enhealth% - %roll%` should be `Set/A enhealth-=roll`.

Comment: Thank you, it works beautifully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes, some are fixes other's are hopefully to help you see a different way of doing things, *(primarily use of `Choice /C` for input selection and `Call :label` to minimize repeating echo'd text.

```bat
@Echo Off
If /I Not "%CD%"=="directoryForscreed" CD /D "directoryForscreed" 2>Nul||Exit/B
For %%A In ("premenupicture" "dice" "atkmenusample" "mainmenuforscreed"
) Do If Not Exist "%%A.txt" Exit/B
Title Forscreed
Color 07
Mode 80,25

:premenu
Echo=
Type premenupicture.txt
Echo=
Choice /C 123 /M "Please type in your choice number: "
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo credits
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo loadgame
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo newgame
ClS
GoTo premenu

:newgame
Set/A "key=chest=level=rank=gold=playwon=playloss=enwon=enloss=dice=prestige=0"
Set/A "atk=def=int=vit=1"
Set "health=100"

:prologue
ClS
Echo Wake up..
Timeout 2 /NoBreak>Nul
ClS
Echo Wake up!
Timeout 2 /NoBreak>Nul
ClS
Call :prologEcho
Choice /C 1234
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo tutorialfinish1
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo caveprologue
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo scavengeprologue
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo prologueboat
GoTo prologue

:prologueboat
ClS
Call :prologueboatEcho
Choice /C 1234
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo prologue
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo prologuemast
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo prologuecaptaincabin
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo prologuedeck
GoTo prologueboat

:prologuedeck
ClS
Echo The deck is empty, except for a satchel. You reach inside and find a Rusty
Echo Pistol and equip it. You walk out off the deck.
Timeout -1

:prologueboat2
ClS
Call :prologueboatEcho
Choice /C 1234
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo prologue
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo prologuemast
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo prologuecaptaincabin
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo prologuedeck2
GoTo prologueboat2

:prologuedeck2
ClS
Echo Nothing here!
Timeout -1
GoTo prologueboat2

:prologuecaptaincabin
ClS
Echo The captain's cabin is tiny. Cramped up, you walk into the room. There is a
Echo bag of gold, a magazine for a pistol, and an old pair of boots. You walk out
Echo of the captain's cabin.
Timeout -1

:prologueboat3
ClS
Call :prologueboatEcho
Choice /C 1234
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo prologue
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo prologuemast
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo prologuecaptaincabin2
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo prologuedeck2
GoTo prologueboat3

:prologuecaptaincabin2
ClS
Echo Nothing here!
Timeout -1
GoTo prologueboat3

:prologuemast
ClS
Echo You climb up the mast. Nothing here! You can use the ropes though, so you
Echo take it off.
Timeout -1

:prologueboat4
ClS
Call :prologueboatEcho
Choice /C 1234
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo prologue
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo prologuemast2
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo prologuecaptaincabin2
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo prologuedeck2
GoTo prologueboat4

:scavengeprologue
ClS
Echo A dice appeared! What do you do with it? Shrugging, you put it in your pocket.
Echo (You can't scavenge anymore after this until you finish the tutorial!)
Set/A dice+=1
Timeout -1

:prologue2
ClS
Call :prologEcho
Choice /C 1234
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo tutorialfinish1
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo caveprologue
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo scavengeprologue2
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo prologueboat
GoTo prologue2

:scavengeprologue2
ClS
Echo Can't scavenge in the tutorial! Complete the tutorial first, then you can
Echo scavenge again.
Timeout -1
GoTo prologue2

:caveprologue
Cls
Echo You walk to the cave and find a warm fire lit up. How was it lit? You don't
Echo know. You quickly scramble to near the fire for warmth, satisfied.
Timeout -1
GoTo prologue

:tutorialfinish1
ClS
Echo You pull out what you found from your pockets. A rusty gun, a magazine for
the gun, and a dice. I wonder what the dice does?
Timeout -1
ClS
Echo The dice rolls in your hand, and you accidentally drop it. It glows golden!
Timeout -1
ClS
Timeout 1 /NoBreak>Nul
Type dice.txt
Echo=
Echo Rolling a 7-sided die...
Timeout 2 /NoBreak>Nul
Set/A roll=(%random% %% 7) + 1
Echo You landed a %roll%!
Timeout -1
ClS
Echo Your objective is to build up a boat to go find the artifacts which end the
Echo game. The game is frequently updated, so check on the website for more quests
Echo and islands, plus new artifacts. The main playing style is fighting,
Echo equipping, trading, buying, leveling, and surviving as best as you can.
Timeout -1
ClS
Type atkmenusample.txt
Echo This is what you'll get upon questing or fighting in the woods! Monsters drop
Echo food, which is what you need to survive. You lose health every time do you a
Echo task, an estimated 0.712 health taken. You can regain the health with food. To
Echo fight, you will normally type in 1 and attack. The golden dice will do
Echo everything for you! The formula consists of your strength, weapons, and the
Echo dice rolled.
Timeout -1
ClS
Echo Then, the enemy takes his turn to attack! The computer will calculate all of
Echo this for you, and deal in the damage. Press 2 to use a health potion, and
Echo press 3 to your gold. If you're feeling it, you can also pass your turn,
Echo allowing the enemy to go. Other that fighting, the game is really mainly about
Echo a mystery storyline, which often requires equipment, gold, and equipment from
Echo quests. You can level up tools this way too. One of the special things about
Echo Forscreed is that there are no "different" swords. It simply levels up your
Echo swords to deal more damage.
Timeout -1
ClS
Echo Let's give attacking a try!
Echo Travel to the main menu:
Timeout -1

:mainmenututorial
ClS
Echo Here we are, at the tutorial. When this tutorial ends, it should look a bit
Echo like this:
Echo=
Type mainmenuforscreed.txt
Echo=
Echo Above is the main menu. You're going to want to attack, so let's hit 1.
Choice /C 1
If Not Errorlevel 1 goto invalidmainmenututorial1
GoTo foresttutorial

:invalidmainmenututorial1
ClS
Echo Invalid answer. You can try the other options soon, for now just press 1.
Timeout -1
GoTo mainmenututorial

:foresttutorial
ClS
Echo=
Echo   __________________________
Echo  ^|                          ^|
Echo  ^|    An enemy appeared!    ^|
Echo  ^| Enemy health: %enhealth% ^|
Echo  ^| Your health: %yourhealth%^|
Echo  ^|                          ^|
Echo  ^|   1. ATK    2. USE POT   ^|
Echo  ^|   3. GOLD   4. PASS      ^|
Echo  ^| _________________________^|
Echo=
Echo Here appears an attack screen! Quick, press 1!
Choice /C 1
If Not ErrorLevel 1 GoTo invalidforesttutorial1
GoTo atkforesttutorial1

:invalidforesttutorial1
ClS
Echo Invalid answer. You can try the other options soon, or now just press 1.
Timeout -1
GoTo foresttutorial

:atkforesttutorial1
ClS
Set/A roll=(%random% %% 7) + 1
Set/A enhealth-=roll
Echo You attacked the enemy!
Echo=
Echo   __________________________
Echo  ^|                          ^|
Echo  ^|    An enemy appeared!    ^|
Echo  ^| Enemy health: %enhealth% ^|
Echo  ^| Your health: %yourhealth%^|
Echo  ^|                          ^|
Echo  ^|   1. ATK    2. USE POT   ^|
Echo  ^|   3. GOLD   4. PASS      ^|
Echo  ^| _________________________^|
Echo=
Timeout -1

Exit/B

:prologEcho
Echo The sea is glimmering.. A broken boat seems to have crashed against a huge
Echo wooden rod. A spiritual tomb of some sort! You remember now. The Queen of
Echo Walkers sent you on a mission to save the kingdom by finding an artifact on
Echo the other side of the world, but you faced a storm and crashed into this
Echo wooden tomb.
Echo=
Echo Night is falling quick, what will you do?
Echo 1. Go to the boat.
Echo 2. Scavenge for resources.
Echo 3. Look around that cave nearby, looks fishy.
Echo 4. I already did all of these.
GoTo :EOF

:prologueboatEcho
Echo You walk to the boat. It's broken at the side, so it can't be used. The
Echo material is also weak. It's been thrashed by heavy waves and can't sail.
Echo Where do you search on the boat?
Echo 1. The deck
Echo 2. The captain's cabin
Echo 3. The mast
Echo 4. Get off boat
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: Fixed it for me, thank you. Not sure I'll be using the choice /c as I just want the choice system to be as it is. But thank you for the solution