# Batch adding variables

Tags: batch-file, variables, error-handling

Let's just say I have variable "enemy health".

I would create that with `set enhealth=100`.
Then I want to make a rolling dice system with a 7 sided die, I would make the code `set /a roll=(%random% %% 7) + 1`. So now `%roll%` is the outcome of the die.

I want to make `%enhealth%` get diminished by the outcome of the roll. So I did 
`set enhealth = %enhealth% - %roll%`.

However, when I do
`echo %enhealth%`  on the next line, it shows as 100, same as before.
How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: How about you take a look at [the entire rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700730/6738015) I provided for you yesterday, which includes that code, or at least comment, reply or mark an answer as the accepted solution. Why should we help if it is ignored?

Comment: Hi, Compo, I decided not to fully use the rewrite seeing that I want to learn code for myself and not take credit for other's works. I tried your rewrite. It was fantastic! But I found that doing it myself was more entertaining and provided a better learning experience. So thank you, but I think I'll just be looking for this piece of code's answer and move on.

Comment: Note, I rechecked the comments you left me, I had only seen one of them. I'm sorry that I hadn't seen that one, thank you for that.

Comment: Well you can learn by reading the help file for a command before asking a question.